# How do this program but in reverse, pattern

Tags: c++, for-loop, repeat

so i want output like this

```
  1
 123
12345
 123
  1
```

i already make the program but it only output these, and im confused how to output the bottom triangle

```
  1
 123
12345
```

here's my program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 3 ;
    int i, j, k;


        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = n; j > i; j--) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= (2 * i - 1); k++) {
                cout << k;
            }
        cout <<endl;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: use string instead and concat at the end and in the beginning each time.

Comment: One issue with the tags -- `design-patterns` doesn't mean fancy looking output.  It has a specific meaning in the world of programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added another for loop exactly like yours with different order from n-1. I modified your code to this:

```
int main() {
    int n = 3 ;
    int i, j, k;


    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = n; j > i; j--) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (k = 1; k <= (2 * i - 1); k++) {
            cout << k;
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (j = n; j > i; j--) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (k = 1; k <= (2 * i - 1); k++) {
            cout << k;
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now it returns:

```
  1
 123
12345
 123
  1
```

Comment: I did not downvote however I suspect the downvote was because you did not explain your changes to the code. Just giving the answer as code is discouraged at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, probably its easy for you. i just start coding here, sometimes i have small problem like that.

Comment: me too, i cant even downvote, and i think for simple code like this, i can understand what he change, i know i should copy my first code and put it under. but i dont know how ro reverse the code. he just change this  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) into this  for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) . only the first line of code

Comment: @carlise You are welcome. I said I modified it in one sec to tell you that your code is already great and you need to modify it a bit to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

@Mojtaba's answer is a perffect extension to your approach.

However, I wanted to provide another method that is generally used in creating such strings that are formatted in a particular manner. It is common to create the entire pattern line by line and then print to the console all at once.

I have appropriately commented the code for your reference and it should be easy to understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void pattern(int n) {
    std::vector<std::string> lines; // store the first n lines to print later
    int length = 2*n - 1; // length of each line

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::string str = std::string(length, ' '); 
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2*i + 1; j++) {
            str[n - i + j - 2] = j + '0'; 
            // indexing can be figured by observing the pattern
        }
        lines.emplace_back(str);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
    }
    
    for(int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    pattern(n);
}
```